# Instalar dlib en pycharm

Tags: pycharm

Estoy intentando instalar un paquete en pycharm al igual que muchas otras veces y no lo consigo. Me sale el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- He actualizado mi pip pero sigue dando el mismo error.
- He visto en un post de SO que recomiendan trabajar con el interprete de anaconda y no con uno virtual, lo cual también he probado y sigue saliendo el mismo error.
- El mensaje pone que instale cmaker y también lo hice desde pycharm y bajándomelo desde su página oficial. Y sigue saliendo que lo instale.

¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

Comment: El texto de error que sale es que necesitas tener instalado CMake ¿lo tienes? Aquí tienes instrucciones sobre cómo instalarlo en windows: https://cmake.org/install/

Comment: En teoría si, me bajé e instalé el: Windows win32-x86 Installer pero sigue saliendo ese mensaje